# How can I get Bootstrap four columns grid span two rows on a second column?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, portfolio

How can I get Bootstrap four columns grid span two rows on a second column?

Hi, if somene can help me to achieve the kind of portfolio grid with 4 columns (see the pic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEEJg.jpg)) where second column span 2 rows. (have a plan to put images with hover caption effect inside).

I tried with this solutions, but havent found the right one. Links below:

> [How can I get a Bootstrap column to span multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/how-can-i-get-a-bootstrap-column-to-span-multiple-rows)
>
> [Row span in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707602/row-span-in-bootstrap-3)
>
> [How to make a div in the middle of two others to span multiple rows, like rowspan in tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053130/how-to-make-a-div-in-the-middle-of-two-others-to-span-multiple-rows-like-rowspa)
>
> [Twitter Bootstrap 3 rowspan and reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241862/twitter-bootstrap-3-rowspan-and-reorder)
>
> [how to create complex grid in bootstrap 3, (column rowspan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139963/how-to-create-complex-grid-in-bootstrap-3-column-rowspan/32147713)
>
> [Twitter Bootstrap 3 rowspan and reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241862/twitter-bootstrap-3-rowspan-and-reorder)

Thank you in advance!

[look the scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu9Bn.jpg)

Comment: Try to use only one row, all floating element could do the trick. If not, post a fiddle to test it.

Comment: It's not really possible to do with Bootstrap's normal Grid. Rowspan is something you can apply to <table>s.

Comment: Any code you can provide?

Comment: Can/did you try nesting like this? http://www.bootply.com/Dxd7yctlwi

Comment: This is the same result as the photo as concerns the structure but the counting is not right. The second item called 5 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all cells have the same height (as the the image shows), all you have to do is create a four columns structure, and within them put one or two elements.

Something like that:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="single-height">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="single-height">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="double-height">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="single-height">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="single-height">
      6
    </div>
  </div>     
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="single-height">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="single-height">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with bootstrap column grid style . The tallest column will push the bottom row . You can do this using masonry which suits very nice with bootstrap grid columns . See it here [Masonry page](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: This is my first post on stack overflow and I'm pretty new in web dev. Masonry seems like a good solution for the issue, will explore, thank you.

Comment: I want my portfolio grid be like on the theme, just without the filtering. Do you still think masonry is a right for it? http://www.themezaa.com/html/h-code/home-architecture.html

Comment: in this example all boxes have the same height so bootstrap it should be good enough i think but if your images height differ so masonry is the only choise . check this page http://www.kristianhammerstad.com/